# Logistic regression and confounders or mediators

Tags: regression, logistic, mediation, confounding

For a researchproject I would like to use the logistic regression model.
I look at the relationship between SES (categorial) and participation in training (dichotomous). Now there are several variables (e.g. age and sex) that can affect the correlation.
How do I best approach this (in SPSS)? Statistical analyzes are quite new to me, so please clarify.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your dependent variable is 'participation in training' (dichotomous), you can create a simple logistic regression model having 'SES' (categorial) as single independent variable. Check the p-value on Wald test for the significance of SES as predictor or, if you have that output, check the confidence intervals for the coefficient. Exponentiate your coefficient to interpret the effect of your predictor (SES) in the outcome (participation). Check the Likelihood Ratio test (LR) for the overall significance of the model.

You can then add more complexity in your model. Include other variables as age or sex, first one at the time, then go for combinations. You can also try interactions (eg. SES:Age). In any case, always carry the previous steps while interpreting the results along the way: are all predictors significant? what is the effect of each predictor in the output when adjusted to other factors? how is the effect of each predictor changing each time you add or remove an additional factor? does it make sense to your model? and is the model significative overall?

If you have many possible independent variables, you can carry an automatic stepwise selection process, backward or forward. If you do, take it as guidance only, for suggestion of a more complex model. You should always build your model manually and critically so that it makes sense to explain the phenomenon that you are trying to model.